# JVM Implementation of FileSystem.list

Tags: java, java-native-interface, filesystems

I'm looking for the JVM implementation of the Java JNI call for FileSystem.list()

I already grepped through the JVM sources (http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/), but didn't find anything.

Can anyone show me the location of the implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were looking in the hotspot directory.

The JNI implementation is under the JDK directory, e.g. the Windows implementation is  [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/windows/native/java/io), in files `Win32FileSystem_md.c` and `WinNTFileSystem_md.c`

Comment: Thank you kind Sir, this is exactly what I was looking for!